# Slow periodic communication matlab-arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-communication

First I send data to Arduino from Matlab, then arduino proceed this data and send a message 'Ready' to Matlab to send him a new one. But this periodic communication is very slow.

This is my Matlab code :

```
for i =1:nbr
arduino_serial= serial('/dev/cu.wchusbserial1410');
set(arduino_serial,'BaudRate',9600);
set(arduino_serial,'Terminator','CR');
fopen(arduino_serial);
pause(1);

 A_string =    strcat(num2str(tabx(i)),',',num2str(taby(i)),',',num2str(pression_ref));

%Send
fprintf(arduino_serial,A_string);
%Receive from Arduino
while (strcmp('Ready',fscanf(arduino_serial,'%f'))==0)
end
fclose(arduino_serial);
delete (arduino_serial);
end
```

My setup in Arduino are :

```
Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
Serial.setTimeout(100);
```

Is there another way to send periodic data?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? Anyway you can leave the port open among transmissions..

Comment: `'BaudRate',9600` is slow. When you say slow, you mean slower than that?

Comment: Try to answer "Which data throughput do you need?". Then two choices: adapt the baud rate accordingly or try another communication protocol with a higher throughput like SPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation, I think that your code is not apt. I have understood that Matlab waits for 'ready' from arduino, then it can send immediately the new message. Thus you dont have to close serial and reopen it each time; this part adds a delay of at least 1s!

You have to put opening and closing serial outside of your for loop.

For reliability you should increase `sleep(1)` to `sleep(2)`.

Moreover there can be garbage in arduino serial buffer before you open it; if you encounter this, then you may read from arduino serial to empty the buffer (just after the sleep(2) instruction).